# Sqllogship.exe: replace with powershell?

Tags: sql-server

To get more control, and to enable another transport. Is there a direct replacement in powershell?

Answer (score 2):

I coded a script to ship logs manually using PowerShell. You can find it [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2013/02/08/manual-log-shipping-with-powershell/)

Basically it does what native Log Shipping does: it takes transaction log backups, copies to a shared folder and restores to the secondary WITH NORECOVERY.

Some limitations apply:

- Only a single secondary is allowed
- No support for STANDBY

I coded it this way because it was enough for what I had to do, which is what you do 99% of the time with log shipping.